# Maven compilation error

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, gwt

> Compiling module com.example.myPackage.GWT.HelloGWT
>   [INFO]    Validating newly compiled units
>       [INFO]       Ignored 1 unit with compilation errors in first pass.
>       [INFO] Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
>       [INFO]    Finding entry point classes
>       [INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/home/ilsurih/Projects/maven%20hibernate/src/main/java/com/example/myPackage/GWT/client/HelloGWT.java'
>       [INFO]          [ERROR] Line 31: No source code is available for type com.example.myPackage.HibernateUtil; did you forget to inherit a required module?
>       [INFO]       [ERROR] Unable to find type 'com.example.myPackage.GWT.client.HelloGWT'
>       [INFO]          [ERROR] Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable
>       [INFO]          [ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly
>       [ERROR] Exception in thread "UnitWriteThread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
>       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>       [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
>       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

This is the `HibernateUtil` class:

```
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        // Close caches and connection pools
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }

    public static List getUsers(){
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        return session.createCriteria(User.class).list();
    }    
}
```

When I call the `getUsers()` method from `main` it works. Something must be wrong with Maven. I tried to remove all Hibernate files. When I run `mvn clean install` it compiles working war archive.

[Here is full project](https://bitbucket.org/IlsurIH/login-page/src)

Comment: Extending Object is redundant code.

Comment: Does com.example.myPackage.HibernateUtil reside in the same project or a different one?

Comment: @JamesB in the same. Here is full project: https://bitbucket.org/IlsurIH/login-page/src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the package `com.example.myPackage` is not part of the source path of your gwt client. So it can not be used on the client side.

Comment: how can in be if it works when i delete all hibernate xml and java files?
here is full project https://bitbucket.org/IlsurIH/login-page/src